# How to display records which is not present in one table, but present in another table using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

[image: sample output]I have 3 table called `Item,Sales,ItemDynamic`

**Item**

```
ID
---
111
112
```

**Sales**

```
ItemID    StoreID
------------------
111       1201
111       2001
111       2400      
111       1400
111       1201
111       1201
111       2400
111       2001
```

**ItemDynamic**

```
ItemID     StoreID
------------------
111       1201
111       1302
111       1400
111       2001
111       2400
111       1500
```

> When you do grouping `Sales.StoreID` with ItemID, it will have only 4 storeID (1201,1400,2001,2400)
>
> Now I want to display only the remaining storeid which is in ItemDynamic.StoreID like below

**Expecting output**

```
ItemID    StoreID
-----------------
111       1302
111       1500
```

I tried in different way, But it brings all the storeid

**Condition**

**1.should not use subquery**

**Tried Not working**

```
SELECT 
    IC.ItemID , IC.StoreID 
FROM 
    ItemDynamic IC
LEFT JOIN 
    Sales S ON S.StoreID = Ic.StoreID
WHERE 
    S.StoreID IS NULL and S.Time between '2017-07-16' and '2017-07-31'
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Sami by using subquery we can easily achieve it. Do you really want to see that. I gave here small piece of table.

Comment: `Tried Not working` ... what is not working?  Other than missing a join condition, your query looks right.

Comment: @mohamedfaiz Well if you set `S.StoreID IS NULL` that mean the `S.Time` is also `Null`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

```
Declare @Item Table (ID INT);
Declare @Sales Table (ItemID INT , StoreID INT);
Declare @ItemDynamic Table (ItemID INT , StoreID INT);

Insert into @Item values
(111),
(112);

Insert into @Sales values
(111,1201),
(111,2001),
(111,2400),
(111,1400),
(111,1201),
(111,1201),
(111,2400),
(111,2001);

Insert into @ItemDynamic values
(111,1201),
(111,1302),
(111,1400),
(111,2001),
(111,2400),
(111,1500);

SELECT IC.ItemID , IC.StoreID FROM @ItemDynamic IC
LEFT JOIN @Sales S ON S.StoreID = Ic.StoreID
WHERE S.StoreID IS NULL;
```

Here is a [Demo](http://rextester.com/JYWF75128)

**Update:**
If the `S.StoreID IS NULL` that mean , there is not date in this rows , there is a `NULL` in the `Time` column.

Comment: I think you need to also join on the `ItemID`.  Also, this is no different than the query given in the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Was writing the demo

Comment: @Sami I saw your demo. It showing correctly. But when I try with the same code and additionally I add time in filter. But it's not bringing any result

Comment: @mohamedfaiz That because you add `AND` , and I think there is no matches in the date you set

Comment: @Timbiegeleisen what do you mean. It has records. I thinks it's not showing due filter by date.

Comment: @mohamedfaiz As I say before , You have no matches in the date range you set

Comment: @Sami I added date on your demo. there also not showing record

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151130/discussion-between-mohamed-faiz-and-sami).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all StoreIDs from `ItemDynamic` who are not also in `Sales` here you go:

```
SELECT distinct StoreID FROM ItemDynamic 
WHERE StoreID not in (SELECT StoreID FROM Sales)
```

Or without the subquery:

```
SELECT distinct ItemDynamic.StoreID FROM ItemDynamic 
LEFT JOIN Sales ON Sales.StoreID = ItemDynamic.StoreID
WHERE Sales.StoreID IS NULL
```

Comment: Sorry, see my condition, shouldn't use subquery

Answer (score 0):

Use a join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ItemDynamic t1
LEFT JOIN Sales t2
    ON t1.ItemID  = t2.ItemID AND
       t1.StoreID = t2.StoreID
WHERE t2.ItemID IS NULL
```